# DSP: stationary non-periodic signal: what's the best causal technique?

Tags: arima

This is a bit DSP-related: so if you turn your non-stationary time series into a stationary process, you'll probably see that it is not periodic.. This is an issue for Fourier-based techniques because they are not local in frequency. Now, besides wavelets (some types are causal btw), which other causal techniques can you use? (and ARMA is not it). I tried Empirical Mode Decomposition (HHT), but that's not causal; I tried Intrinsic Time-scale Decomposition: not causal either. Wavelets are pretty old and I would think something better would have been "discovered" by now? Does anyone know of a good causal signal processing technique that deals well with non-periodicity? Thanks!!

Comment: Have you managed to implement some causal versions of wavelets with success?

Answer (score 3):

I know only that Jurik's JMA is good causal filter, better than Kalman and Volterra filters, but I don't know for sure what algorithm inside - it's black box. Does anybody know better causal filter?

Comment: Do you of anyone else have more information about this filter? I can only find the author's website and I'm not convinced by it.

Comment: @Bootvis Code for the JMA is available here [link](http://www.forex-tsd.com/metatrader-4/2702-jurik-indicators-mt4.html)

Comment: @Bootvis I can recommend you to read this doc for more information:[link](http://www.jurikres.com/down/ma_evolv.pdf).

Comment: @babelproofreader I've used this code for MT4, but it's not Jurik original. So their quality is little bit different than original ones.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with wavelets is that you'll have some boundary distortions so be careful when exploiting the results.

Comment: Could you have a look at http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/9976/how-to-eliminate-border-effects-on-wavelet-denoising

Answer (score 2):

Wavelets and Kalman filtering.

Comment: Wavelet is not a causal technique. there is a huge boundery effect due to the selection of either "reflection" of "periodic"